# How do I safely shrink the size of an active git repository?

Tags: git

We have a very large repository (> 5GiB) on a central git server.  With a series of prunes, repacks and gcs on my local clone, I was able to reduce its size significantly.

Here's the sequence I used:

```
git repack -A -d
git prune-packed
git gc --prune=now
git repack -a -d -f --depth=250 --window=250
git prune
git prune-packed
```

(some of this may be redundant)

Which of these operations are safe to use on an active repository?  Ideally we would not need to lock the server repository while the housekeeping is done and people can branch/push/pull/merge to their heart's content while the size optimization happens in the background.

The Google returns contradictory information.  For example http://marc.info/?l=git&m=117025831200311 says `git gc --prune` is unsafe on an active repository but says `git gc` is fine.  But `--prune` is on by default in git-gc.

I have not been able to find anything else that talks about the safety of these operations on an active repository.  The manpages are silent on the issue.

Comment: Thanks Dan Lowe for the cleanup!